# run user script on chrome://settings and similar urls

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

Why doesn't tampermonkey work on urls such as `chrome://history/` or `chrome://settings/`? Any way to run an user script on this pages as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible, because the `chrome` scheme (`chrome://`) isn't supported in `@match`'s abilities.

UserScripts also use Chrome's [`match`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) spec, so a Chrome extension to do that wouldn't work either.

From the linked spec:

> Host permissions and content script matching are based on a set of URLs defined by match patterns. A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (`http`, `https`, `file`, or `ftp`, and that can contain '`*`' characters).

Comment: Note that this is true, for Tampermonkey, irregardless of the setting of the `extensions-on-chrome-urls` flag. BUT, **full Chrome extensions CAN run** against `chrome://` pages if the user is foolish enough to set that flag.