# Tampermonkey Script Doesn't Work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I recently asked a question about how to get this script to run every time I go to chrome://extensions: "document.getElementById("joodangkbfjnajiiifokapkpmhfnpleo").remove();"

Someone answered and stated that I should enable extensions on chrome:// and that I should make a "content script." 
I have enabled "chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls" and after some googling, I think the "content script" that the user was referring to could be a userscript on Tampermonkey. So, I attempted to create a script on tampermonkey, but it didn't work and I don't know what's wrong with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tampermonkey Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    chrome://extensions/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remove Extension Visually
// @author       Omega
// @match        chrome://extensions*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';

// Your code here...
var elmDeleted = document.getElementById("joodangkbfjnajiiifokapkpmhfnpleo");
elmDeleted.parentNode.removeChild(elmDeleted);
})();
```

Comment: does tampermonkey allow `chrome://extensions*` scripts? [no it does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228669/run-user-script-on-chrome-settings-and-similar-urls/36382734)

Comment: Although a Chrome *Extension* can be configured to run on `chrome://` pages, Tampermonkey does not support this.